# Hardware timer instantly completes when first used. STM32F303VC

Tags: rust, timer, embedded, stm32

I'm attempting to setup and use the `TIM2` peripheral in one pulse mode (OPM) on the `STM32F303 Discovery` board.

The issue I'm encountering is that the timer *instantly* completes after enabling it.

I'm not using `interrupt`'s at this point and I'm just polling the `TIM2_SR`(status register) `UIF` bit to determine if the timer has completed.

This only happens the first time I enable the timer, if I use the timer again it works correctly (does not complete instantly).

I've tried resetting the `TIM2_CNT` register prior to enabling the timer but the result is the same.

```
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use stm32f3xx_hal::pac;


#[entry]
fn main( ) -> ! {
    let p = pac::Peripherals::take( ).unwrap( );

    p.RCC.apb1enr.modify( | _, w | w.tim2en( ).set_bit( ) );

    p.TIM2.cr1.write( | w | w
        .urs( ).set_bit( )
        .opm( ).set_bit( )
        .cen( ).clear_bit( ) );

    // I've tried resetting the CNT register at this point
    // in the application but the result was the same. 
    
    // Set the prescaler based on an 8MHz clock.
    p.TIM2.psc.write( | w | w.psc( ).bits( 7999 ) );

    // Here I initialize an LED (GPIOE). I've removed this code to 
    // keep the example as clean as possible.

    let delay = | duration | {         

        p.TIM2.arr.write( | w | w.arr( ).bits( duration ) ); 

        // I've also tried resetting the CNT register here 
        // but the result was the same.       
        p.TIM2.cr1.modify( | _, w | w.cen( ).set_bit( ) );

        while p.TIM2.sr.read( ).uif( ).bit_is_clear( ) { }

        p.TIM2.sr.write( | w | w.uif( ).clear_bit( ) );
    };

    // Enable LED.

    // This call instantly returns.
    delay( 3999 );

    // Disable LED.

    loop { }
}
```

The example above gets the LED to flicker on and off with little to no delay.
If I instead use an endless loop the timer works as intended after the initial call to `delay`.

```
loop {

    // Enable LED.

    // The first call in the first loop iteration
    // returns instantly.
    delay( 3999 );

    // Disable LED.
    
    // This call, and every call here after correctly
    // returns after 4 seconds.
    delay( 3999 );
}
```

I've examined the registers while the application is running and everything appears to be set up correctly.

- The `TIM2_CNT` register reads `0x0000_0000` prior to enabling the timer
- The `UIF` bit in the `TIM2_SR` register is not set prior to enabling the timer
- The `TIM2_PSC` register reads the correct pre-scale `7999`
- The `TIM2_ARR` register contains the correct auto reload value `3999`
- The `OPM` bit in the `TIM_CR1` register is set correctly

After reading a similar issue on a different forum it was suggested in that answer to enable the `URS` bit in the `TIM2_CR1` register, which causes an update interrupt/DMA request to only be issued on counter overflow/underflow. This of course did not work.

I get the sense that there is a `bit` somewhere that I need to reset/set in order to get the timer to function as expected the first time I enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after re-reading the section on timers in the manual I found the following:

> The new prescaler ratio is taken into account at the next update event.

OK, so how can I generate an update event via software in order for the prescaler value to get updated prior to starting the timer. That's when I found this (emphsis mine):

> In upcounting mode, the counter counts from 0 to the auto-reload value (content of the
> TIMx_ARR register), then restarts from 0 and generates a counter overflow event.
> ***An Update event can be generated at each counter overflow or by setting the UG bit in the TIMx_EGR register*** (by software or by using the slave mode controller).

So after setting the `prescaler` value I then set the `UG` bit in the `TIM2_EGR` register.

```
// Set the prescaler based on an 8MHz clock.
p.TIM2.psc.write( | w | w.psc( ).bits( 7999 ) );

// Generate an update event so that the new prescaler
// value gets loaded.
p.TIM2.egr.write( | w | w.ug( ).update( ) );
```

After forcing an update the timer started to work correctly every time (including the first time).

So, to sum up my issue `RT*M`...